# Sort an array of name and dates

Tags: java

I have an array of string folder names, each of which include a date, time, and timezone. The array is as so:

```
[
    "folder_name_01-18-2020-19_00_00_PM_EST",
    "folder_name_05-01-2019-00_00_00_AM_EDT",
    "folder_name_12-15-2019-02_00_00_AM_EST"
]
```

How can I sort this array so that all the folder names are sorted in ascending order by their date (earliest to latest), eg. the result of the above array should be this:

```
[
    "folder_name_05-01-2019-00_00_00_AM_EDT",
    "folder_name_12-15-2019-02_00_00_AM_EST",
    "folder_name_01-18-2020-19_00_00_PM_EST"
]
```

The folder name strings are guarenteed to be in this exact format. `folder_name` never changes, so only the time stamp will change for each folder name.

I've thought of a high level solution that sounds very inefficient:

```
Isolate the datetime from the folder name
Map the datetime to full folder name: {"05-01-2019-00_00_00_AM_EDT":"folder_name_05-01-2019-00_00_00_AM_EDT"}
Add the isolated datetime to an array
Sort the array of datetimes // potential trouble spot b/c of the date format
result = new array()
For item in sorted array:
    result.add(map.get(item))
return result
```

I'm wondering if improvements and/or better methods could be used to solve this problem

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Can you give us some code?

Comment: Another reason, as if we needed one more, to require that date formats always be presented in major/minor format e.g. YYYY-MM-DD format. And specifically never, ever in US format (MM-DD-YYYY), the worst of all options.

Comment: @Pablo Added my own thoughts to the original post

Comment: The inclusion of the timezone is important here. You're going to have to parse these fragments to actual date/time values for comparison. You can't use simple string comparisons.

Comment: The format of those file names is terrible… learn about the ISO 8601 standard for formats to use when exchanging date-time values as text. And never use 2-4 letter pseudo time zones such as `EDT` & `EDT`, as they are not standardized and are not even unique! Real time zone names are in the format of `Continent/Region` such as `America/Montreal`.   Even better, learn to adjust into UTC.

Comment: Filenames generally aren't allowed to contain `/`.

Comment: Don't look at me... the folder names are auto generated from a completely separate system that I have no ability to change. Folders are tossed over from the other side of the wall and I have to work with what I'm given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a much better solution using a custom `Comparator`: Grab the date time using the `substring()` function, parse it with `SimpleDateTime`, grab the epoch time from the resulting `Date` objects and then use `Long.compare()` to determine which time is later.

Answer (score 0):

Your high level solution is not particularly inefficient. However, there is an even more efficient route:

```
Arrays.sort(theArray, Comparator.comparing(CALCFUNCTION));
```

where the CALCFUNCTION bit is a function that calculates a value which will be used for sorting order. What you're looking for is to turn `folder_name_01-18-2020-19_00_00_PM_EST` into `20201801190000` which is easy to do with a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/package-summary.html).

Example:

```
private static final Pattern EXTRACTOR = Pattern.compile(
  "^.*_(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+_\\d+_\\d+)_[AP]M_[A-Z]{1,4}$");

Arrays.sort(theArray, Comparator.comparing(elem -> {
    var m = EXTRACTOR.matcher(elem);
    if (!m.matches()) return "uhoh. That was unexpected.";
    return m.group(3) + m.group(2) + m.group(1) + m.group(4);
}));
```

Comment: How would this function account for something like daylight savings changes? eg: `11-03-2019-01_00_00_AM_EDT` is earlier than `11-03-2019-01_00_00_AM_EST` yet both would be represented as `20190311010000`

Comment: @erli — your comment here is spot on. No amount of regex matching or string manipulation is going to solve this; you **must** turn these into date/times with proper timezones. My first approach would probably be looking at Java's [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class.

Comment: The exact format of the date string is non-common and not specified. Yup, convert to a relevant java.time type first (these are fortunately comparable as well, generally), but given that the format is quite confusing, baby steps.